# Integrate confirm email system in opencart module?

Tags: opencart

I am totally new for opencart and I want to integrate confirm email system in opencart newsletter subscriber module can any one help me?

Comment: Is this *newsletter subscriber module* meant like an extension that You have downloaded/purchased from somewhere? If the answer is YES, then please ask the module developer(s) for support. SO is not about requesting people here to do the job for You, but to help You with Your programming problem. You are very welcome to come back with some piece of code that is not working for You and we may help identify and solve the problem. Please understand that people here willing to help for free are (usually) not willing to also do You whole piece of work for free...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this extension http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=1707

Answer (score -1):

For Registration/order confirmation mail you have to change some store settings in your admin panel..

**New registration confirmation mail**

Admin panel->system->options tab-> **New Account Alert Mail** = **set as Yes**

for order confirmation mail   **New Order Alert Mail = set as yes**

**Newsletter subscription**

Install **Fix send mail Newsletter** by author **Leandro R.P.P.O**
then activate it...
Then 
**Admin panel->Marketing->Mails-> select all news letter subscribers -> make your message ->send**